# Dockerfile and dpkg command

Tags: dependencies, dockerfile, dpkg

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile to install VuFind.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
#Name of container: docker-vufind:3

# Pull base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER xxx  "xxx@mail.com"

#Install latest patches
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    && apt-get install -y wget 

#Obtain the package
RUN wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/vufind/vufind_3.1.1.deb?use_mirror=osdn -O vufind_3.1.1.deb

#Install it
RUN dpkg -i vufind_3.1.1.deb

#Install VuFind's dependecies
RUN apt-get install -y -f
```

I launched these commands on my Ubuntu's bash and the software worked fine, but it seems that I can't obtain the same result with the Dockerfile because the dpkg command failed for the lack of the dependencies.

```
The command '/bin/sh -c dpkg -i vufind_3.1.1.deb' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is installing the dependecies (Apache, jdk, php...) before the dpkg command line the only way to create a working Dockerfile or is there a shorter way ?

Comment: Just a quick FYI, but you can ignore the wget install and use the cmd
`ADD http:\\path\to\file.txt file.txt'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not the most elegant but:

```
# continue executing even if command fails
RUN dpkg -i vufind_3.1.1.deb || true
```

Comment: Isn't the last line unnecessary? I.e. apt-get install -f would also install previously attempted deb package.

Comment: Indeed, last line is not needed anymore. Everything should be solved after second command.

Comment: Ain't there a way to run `dpkg -i package.deb` with dependencies in one command instead of having to run `apt-get install -f` afterwards, which is ugly and annoying?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger ``dpkg`` is not able to resolve dependencies because it only manages packages, not repositories (like ``yum`` or ``apt``)

Comment: I'm not sure why the line `apt-get install -y -f` was removed. Perhaps it was something specific to a later version of VuFind. I came here trying to install dependencies for wkhtmltopdf because `dpkg -i ...` was saying `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox: wkhtmltox depends on fontconfig; however:  Package fontconfig is not installed... `, etc. The line `apt-get install -y -f` installed all dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

With apt version [1.1~exp11](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/a/apt/stable_changelog) (which is available since Ubuntu 16.04), you are able to install .deb files and resolve dependencies directly with `apt` alone:

```
apt install ./vufind_3.1.1.deb
```

Mind the `./`!

Comment: Thank you! This is gold. And they same `apt` has nothing new except the fancy loading bar :D

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more elegant.

```
# Run both commands together
RUN dpkg -i vufind_3.1.1.deb; apt-get install -y -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a found a cleaner alternative, at least for my case. Since `apt`'s CLI is not stable (as they warn during the Docker build), I opted to work with the package `gdebi-core` which can isntall `.deb` packages and its dependecies:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi /path/to/filename.deb
```

Check this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/698249/1040750) on Superuser for more details/