# Installing phantomjs binary on arm64 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phantomjs, arm64

It appears that a phantomjs package is available for arm64 architecture... [see here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/phantomjs) and particularly [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/arm64/phantomjs/download)... it's for  `focal (20.04LTS)`.

But I'm trying to install the phantomjs binary on the following system:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

# uname -i
aarch64
```

Is this possible?  Or are there any way to install a phantomjs binary on this system?

Comment: PhantomJS is abandonware. You should consider https://pptr.dev

Comment: @GillesQuénot I'm aware of that, and have had a puppeteer version working alongside my phantomjs version for some time, but right now the phantomjs version is still outperforming the puppeteer version... hence I want to keep it for now... and I want to try it on arm64 (have been on amd64 for years).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks possible by adding

```
$ sudo -s
# echo 'deb [arch=arm64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/phantomjs.list
# apt update
# apt policy phantomjs
phantomjs:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 2.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1
Version table:
   2.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1 500
      500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
```

You need to change repository/mirror to serve your special architecture arch64.

---

Another alternative

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phantomjs/2.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1/+build/19118060/+files/phantomjs_2.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1_arm64.deb
$ sudo apt install ./phantomjs_2.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1_arm64.deb
$ sudo apt install -f # if dependencies are not happy
```

Comment: When running `apt update` I get the following errors: `Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages || 404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80] || E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80] || E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: I also get quite a few `Ign:x` lines, like `Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages`

Comment: And then there is no candidate available when running `apt policy phantomjs`.

Comment: Try to find another base url/repository that serves arm64

Comment: But those commands work on your arm64 host?

Comment: No, tested with amd64 (that works)

Comment: What about this source: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phantomjs/2.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1/+build/19118060 ?

Comment: Ah, that seems to work!  I was getting dependency errors with `dpkg -i` ... how does running `apt install -f` *after* fix this?  I would expect there to be some way of doing this as an option to `dpkg -i`... what is the interaction between `dkpg` and `apt` here?

Comment: This is all the Debian magic. Check `man apt-get` and `man dpkg`

Comment: Ha, OK thanks!  And is there a platform-independent way to install via dpkg in this case, rather than referring to a platform-specific download file, e.g. for use in a Dockerfile that might be running on either arm or amd?  Because this phantomjs binary is available for both: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phantomjs/2.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1/+build/19118059

Comment: This is off topic for this question

Comment: I guess it is :-/

Comment: BTW it seems like you can use `apt` to install directly from the deb file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814339/4070848

Comment: I see you've edited your answer to use `apt` rather than `dpkg` to install the deb file, but you still need the `-f` option to fix broken dependencies, like you were doing with the separate `apt install -f` line in your previous version.

Comment: Revised answer is fine except that the `-f` option can just be used in the first `apt install` without any need for the second, but I suppose that you've separated them to make it clear that `-f` may or may not be necessary.

Comment: Bless you, works, I just also needed to setup variable otherwise phantom was unable to connect to display and failing `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen`